# Why is fgets + explode faster than fgetcsv?

Tags: php, csv

I need a quick line-by-line reading of a large csv file, with a partition of the fields into an array.
The csv file has 100 thousand lines.

```
// Example 1, works in 3.5 seconds
if(false !== $handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";"))) {
        $arData[] = $data;
    }
}

// Example 2, works in 0.3 seconds
if(false !== $handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
    while(($data = fgets($handle))) {
        $arData[] = explode(";", $data);
    }
}
```

Why such a serious difference in speed? Or am I doing something wrong?

The documentation says that `fgetcsv` is a similar function to `fgets`, except that it splits the result into an array.

Comment: Are you testing this from the command line? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: php version 7.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fgetcsv` does not simply split the line around new lines and commas... it parses the file character by character from beginning till the end, handling special cases such as:

```
aaa,"bbb
ccc",ddd
```

And:

```
aaa,"bbb,ccc",ddd
```

(both of the above should result in a 1x3 array). It should be ***slower*** than a simple `fgets` + `explode`.